# How to use Cosine Distance matrix for Clustering algorithms like mean-shift, DBSCAN, and optics?

Tags: clustering, k-means, dbscan, python-3.x, mean-shift

I am trying to compare different clustering algorithms for my text data. I first calculated the tf-idf matrix and used it for the cosine distance matrix (cosine similarity). Then I used this distance matrix for K-means and Hierarchical clustering (ward and dendrogram). I want to use the distance matrix for mean-shift, DBSCAN, and optics.

Below is the part of the code showing the distance matrix.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

#define vectorizer parameters
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000,
                                 min_df=0.2, stop_words='english',
                                 use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, ngram_range=(1,3))

%time tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(Strategies) #fit the vectorizer to synopses


terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
dist = 1 - cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix)
print(dist)
```

I am new to both python and clustering. I found the code for K-means and hierarchical clustering and tried to understand it but I cannot apply it for other clusterings algorithms. 
It would be very helpful if I can get some simple explanation of each clustering algorithm and how this distance matrix can be used to implement (if possible) in different clustering.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Several scikit-learn clustering algorithms can be fit using cosine distances:

```py
from collections      import defaultdict
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cluster  import DBSCAN, OPTICS

# Define sample data
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data

# List clustering algorithms
algorithms = [DBSCAN, OPTICS] # MeanShift does not use a metric

# Fit each clustering algorithm and store results
results = defaultdict(int)
for algorithm in algorithms:
    results[algorithm] = algorithm(metric='cosine').fit(X)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but I am getting an error. NameError: name 'clustering_algorithms' is not defined. Also, what would be X? Where I would be using 'dist' which I have calculated (in my code)? Please can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I had a typo; I fixed it. `X` is the standard name for a data array in scikit-learn. You don't need `dist`, use `cosine_distances` instead.

Comment: Does that mean that I should replace X with tfidf_matrix (as visible from my code above)? When I did that I again got an error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'metric'.

Comment: Sorry for my naive questions.

Comment: Got `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead` while working with `DBSCAN`, changing `metric=cosine_distances` to `metric='cosine'` worked.

Comment: This does not work for MeanShift.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.